# Literal parenthesis with python regex

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

I have a dictionary ( e.g. English - Croatian). It may contain sentences and phrases. I'm translating a file of form `"english text" = "english text"` into form `"english text" = "croatian text"` and using python regex module to do so. 
The regex I'm using looks like this (given variable *original* which is text in English that should be translated:

```
regexString = '(?<= = ")'+original+'(?=")'
```

That way I'am able to capture exactly the english text inside the quotes on the right-hand side and substitute it with Croatian. However, the problem appears if the original text contains parenthesis inside. In example:

```
original = 'This is a wonderland :)'
```

In that case an error "unbalanced parenthesis" is raised. If *original* would be hard-coded, I could solve the problem by putting

```
original = 'This is a wonderland :\\)'
```

However, there is a whole file full of *original * variables.
Is there any solution to this problem other than changing *original* variable by preceeding all parenthesis in it with a backslash?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, why **double** backslash?

Comment: The backslash needs to be escaped because it could otherwise start an escape sequence, depending on the character that follows it. While `\)` is unambiguous (and will be translated by the Python interpreter into `\\)` automatically), other sequences like `\n`, `\b` etc. have special meaning. It's good practice to make this explicit, either by doubling the backslashes or by using raw strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to handle this:

```
regexString = '(?<= = ")' + re.escape(original) + '(?=")'
```